# Command instead of 'Goto' in C# VSTO

Tags: c#, vsto

what is another command for 'Goto' ? I am using VSTO to make a ribbon for excel and is doesnt seem to support Goto, and I am trying to create a loop.

Edit: This is the loop i am trying to create :

```
   TimeSpan startTimeSpan = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 0, 20);

    TimeSpan timeDecrease = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1);

    private Timer timer = new Timer();

    public void Ribbon_Load(Office.IRibbonUI ribbonUI)
    {
        timer.Interval = 1000;
        this.ribbon = ribbonUI;
        timer.Tick += timer_Tick;
        timer.Start();
    }

    private void timer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (startTimeSpan.ToString() != "00:00:00")
        {
        startTimeSpan = startTimeSpan - timeDecrease;
        ribbon.InvalidateControl("timerLabel");
        }
        else
        {

 //when timer drop to "00:00:00" then loop to "TimeSpan startTimeSpan = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 0, 20);"

        }
    }
```

Comment: What on earth are you talking about? Just write a loop.

Comment: Goto is never the answer, no matter what the question is (unless you're working in assembly language, or the question is "which statement should I never use?")

Comment: DO NOT USE A GO TO....... USE `break;` `continue;` in a loop instead....

Comment: thanks for that, relatively knew to C#

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably want to be using a `while` loop, with the exit condition in the `while` statement, and use `break` to quit the loop before the exit condition is reached, or `continue` to skip the current iteration of the loop and go on to the next.

Comment: i have edited my post to explain then reason and if you can help me, cheers

Comment: All you need to do in your 'else' is to set startTimeSpan to 20 seconds and return. The timer is still running, and will continue to call you every second.

Comment: i tried that at first, but didnt know the correct syntax to do so

Comment: startTimeSpan = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 0, 20); return;

Answer (score 0):

C# does support goto command, but it isn't for looping. Jump statements are very often not the best solution.

goto - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/13940fs2.aspx

If you are trying to loop just use a looping statement.

looping - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms228598(v=vs.90).aspx

Answer (score 0):

You can find a lot of q&a on excel VSTO.

Whats wrong with something like:

```
for (int i = selectedRange.Rows.Count; i > 0; i--)
{
  ---YOUR CODE HERE---
}
```

OR

```
foreach (Excel.Range row in rng.Areas[1].Rows)
{
   ---YOUR CODE HERE---
}
```